# How to take input from user?

Tags: plotting

Since I'm new to *Mathematica* I want to have a Notebook which takes inputs from user and returns average of the inputs entered and plots it on x-y coordinate.  How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)

Answer (score 4):

This might be an example:

```
x = Input["Insert x coordinates (put them between {} brackets)",{}];
y = Input["Insert y coordinates (put them between {} brackets)",{}];
Mean[x]
Mean[y]
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}]]
```

Comment: Also check out `tutorial/RequestingInput` and `tutorial/TextualInputAndOutputOverview` in the Documentation Center (You can access it from the help menu, and I highly recommend the broadcasts on http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=86 to get you comfortable with mathematica)

Comment: Thanks.
I will try it out. Actually i never mention my real problem but if any problem occur i will revert to stackexchange.com.
Also can you tell me the best tutuorial for starter as i have to solve a simple problem(complex for starter) and submit before Thursday.

Comment: @Soum You could start from [here](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/handsonstart/). The Documentation is also a good place to start, for instance, for [plotting](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/DataVisualization.html). And, this [collection](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) of resources is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

The question says "take input from the user", but this suggest a paradigm more suitable to another programming language. If what you $really$ want is to give the user a way to enter the data and then obtain the required plot, it's more straightforward to just define a function:

```
meanPlot[x_List, y_List] := 
   Module[{xbar = Mean[x], ybar = Mean[y]},
          Print[{xbar, ybar}];
          ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], 
          Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{xbar, ybar}]}]
          ]
```

And then use this so:

```
meanPlot[{5, 2, 9, 4}, {2, -1, 8, 2}]
```

The definition of `meanPlot` does minimal argument-checking (just that each argument is a list). And there are neater ways to combine the printout of the two means with the plot, e.g., use a `Column` construct or label the point of means with its coordinates.